# Programming Go, using Unified Modelling Language Diagrams

Tags: go, uml, paradigms

I have just started using Go (GoLang) and I am finding it a great language. However, after many years of UML and the Object Oriented methods, I find that modelling Go programs (Reverse engineering) is a bit problematic, in that Go Structs contain properties/state, but no methods, and methods/functions that use Structs as parameters (even the ones that do magic so that it makes a Struct look like an object), don't contain methods, or state.

Does this mean I should be using another Methodology to model a Go Program or does UML sufficiently model the language constructs?

Yes I know that if you use methods on the Structs that the behavior of an object in UML can be mapped into Go via a combination of a Struct and a Struct Method, but I am finding this to be wrong, an impedance mismatch in paradigms of sorts.

Is it time for a new (perish the thought!) diagramming technique, for the brave new world where behavior is no longer controlled by an object? can behavior be modeled without reference to the state that it is affecting?

**Update:**

I am trying Data Flow Diagrams out, to see if they fit better to the paradigm. So far so good, but I think I am going to come unstuck when I model the Methods of a Struct, the compromise in the DFD being that they are treated as Functions. :(

Go supports inheritance!!! arghhh!!! (head is blown clean off.) you can compose a Struct which is made of another Struct, which has methods, that the Sub Struct now inherits...you getting this? my mind is blown. Means that UML IS valid...fully but it feels dirty.

Go Does not support inheritance, it just appears so. :) DFD's it is then!

Comment: You'd get some good feedback on [programmers.se], but probably not here.  This is more whiteboard than keyboard, if you understand my meaning.

Comment: Without the whiteboard, there is no keyboard. Paradigms are software, there is no dichotomy in this discussion.

Comment: Step away from the pipe.

Comment: Move away from the keyboard Damien. :-)

Comment: This question and some of the answers may confuse the question of [Is Go an object-oriented language](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language). For those interested, this is on the [Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Is_Go_an_object-oriented_language) and there is also a [useful blog article](http://spf13.com/post/is-go-object-oriented/) as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UML still gives you tools useful for analysis and design of components, interfaces, and data. Go is not an OO language, so you cannot use inheritance, polymorphism, methods, etc. You don't need a new paradigm, you may need an old one: [Structured Analysis and Structured Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_analysis).

Comment: I agree. Not an answer though. Go isn't a strict OO language but then again, neither is object COBOL.

Comment: SSADM? crikey, that's an old one. 1970's? Don't think it would work, hence the new paradigm. SSADM was used back in the days of data analysis, procedure calls and functional decomposition.

Comment: please read above, it didn't quite work, I found inheritance.

Comment: Note that a UML activity diagram containing actions and data stores is equivalent to a DFD. You can also "level" the actions.

Comment: No DFD's are different. Take a look at DFD's in SSADM, you will find they are vastly different from an age of Functional Decomposition, and none of this new Objects nonsense ;) (I studied SSADM for 6 years)

Comment: I used DFDs for a few years as well. Please explain a DFD that doesn't map to an activity diagram.

Comment: An activity diagram doesn't actually model code. DFD's do. There are multiple levels of DFD, the idea being that the code will be functional, procedural, and the lower you go, the deeper the nesting of the functions/procedures. Its a different paradigm. Activity diagrams, are all about Object discovery, DFD's about actual code.

Comment: The new [Alf](http://www.omg.org/spec/ALF/) specification from the OMG contradicts your statement: "A primary goal of an action language is to act as the surface notation for specifying executable behaviors within a wider model that is primarily represented using the usual graphical notations of UML. For example, this might include methods on the operations of classes or transition effect behaviors on state machines." Alf converts straight into activity models and back again.

Comment: "Activity diagrams, are all about Object discovery"? Huh? Activity diagrams can also nest (i.e., level) as deep as you want to go.

Comment: But is what exactly is an activity when you get down to coding? Its not an Object. A DFD Box can be mapped to a function or Procedure.

Comment: Don't get me started on flipping state machines. Currently reverse engineering some numb nuts idea of a state machine, written in C# that communicates with Modbus/TCP. Not fun. And UML is not going to rescue me.

Comment: DFD's are for Procedural, functional Decomposition type languages, whilst Activity Diagrams are just more pot boiler rubbish, that apparently have some profound implication in object discovery, that lead us on to the zen of la la land. What exactly is an Activity, it is a statement, describing a task. But this task is not a Method, an Object, a function or a procedure. Its just a statement of intent, that flows onto another statement of intent.

Comment: Perhaps Zen of la la land was a bit harsh, some of the high level DFD's are zen of la la land too, in recollection.

Comment: No Thanks, I read a couple of books from the OMG a couple of years back, they are way too into objects for my liking. You think like an object too much then you forget that an object is a concept not a fact. Yes you can think like an object, and smell like an object, and all the other propaganda rubbish that I have heard from the OMG, but at the end of the day, its just a paradigm of thought, as equal and inferior to any other paradigms out there. Just that Objects had a great sales push in the early 90's. Much like the sales push of XML in the late 90's. Concepts that seem "shiny" sell books.

Comment: No disrespect to you Jim, and I hope you didn't take any, just that I am only now after many years seeing the light that objects don't work for everything.

Answer (score 8):

The fact that methods are declared outside the definition of the struct itself should not be significant; it is just a minor syntax difference. The methods belong to the struct type just as surely as if they were inside the braces. (They are declared outside the braces because methods aren't limited to structs.)

The real potential problem with using UML with Go is that UML is normally used with traditional object-oriented design (i.e. class hierarchies), and Go takes a different approach to inheritance and polymorphism. Maybe UML can be adapted to Go's type system—I'm not familiar enough with UML to say—but your design approach will probably need to change somewhat whether you continue using UML or not.

Go is not intended to be used in the everything-is-an-object style of Smalltalk and Java. Idiomatic Go programs generally contain a large percentage of procedural code. If your design process focuses on object modeling, it will not work well for Go.

Comment: I don't agree with the 'just syntax' thought process, if that was case then go would just go along with the object paradigm.

Comment: Go does do composition of data structs, also because functions are first class, these can be passed about in a composite style.

Comment: You still can do object based design, and code it in go. However I feel that if we did this we are loosing the true power of programming through composition. I would like to model systems, thinking in this new way. But normal uml composition is all about their object, not the data v function arguments of old in the days of structured analysis, where data was modelled on data flow.

Comment: @WeNeedAnswers (on 'just syntax') I'm not saying that the distinctives of Go's object model are just syntax; I'm saying that they have nothing to do with the differences in how methods are declared. The method-declaration format is an unusual syntax; the replacement of inheritance with embedding is a semantic difference.

Comment: But the semantic difference is key. The syntax has nothing to do with the design decision. The decision was purposeful. Yes You can model a system in UML and Go will adapt, modelling the constructs equally well as a pure OO language, without compromise. However, does this design choice of using UML impede the true nature of the design decision, thus compromising the efforts of the language designers to direct us plebeians in a new direction. In my mind Go is a definite statement of intent and not something to take lightly. In my question I was asking about reverse engineering Go code into UML.

Answer (score 0):

> Go Structs contain properties/state, but no methods, and
>   methods/functions that use Structs as parameters (even the ones that
>   do magic so that it makes a Struct look like an object), don't contain
>   methods, or state.

As you may know, in C++ you can also declare methods on structs - just as in classes with the only difference that you won't be able to use access modifiers.

In OOP languages you declare methods of a class inside the class definition, giving the feeling that these methods are somehow part of the class. This is not true for most languages and Go makes this obvious.

When you declare something like the following pseudo-code in a traditional OOP language:

```
class Foo {
    public function bar(x int) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

the linker will export a function that will look something like:

```
Foo__bar(this Foo, x int)
```

When you then do (assume `f` is an instance of `Foo`):

```
f.bar(3)
```

you are in fact (and indirectly, more on that later) doing:

```
Foo__bar(f, 3)
```

The class instance itself will only contain a so called *vtable* with function pointers to the methods it implements and/or inherits.

Additionally, methods do not contain state, at least not in the contemporary programming world.

> Does this mean I should be using another Methodology to model a Go
>   Program or does UML sufficiently model the language constructs?

UML should suffice.

> Is it time for a new (perish the thought!) diagramming technique, for
>   the brave new world where behavior is no longer controlled by an
>   object?

Naa.

> Can behavior be modeled without reference to the state that it is
>   affecting?

Yes, that's what interfaces are for.

> I am trying Data Flow Diagrams out, to see if they fit better to the
>   paradigm. So far so good, but I think I am going to come unstuck when
>   I model the Methods of a struct, the compromise in the DFD being that
>   they are treated as Functions. :(

Do not get lost in abstractions, break them. There is no perfect paradigm and there will never be.

Comment: Yes I agree there is no perfect paradigm, I have developed in many languages probably like yourself, however Go is new in that it offers a new perspective on language design. There is nothing new in Go's paradigm, Python has done it for quite some time (first parameter of a method is always a reference to the object that owns that method), but the interest to me is the declaration that the developers of the language have made, does this mean that they expect greater things than Objects, have Objects failed. Makes you think, should you use UML if the language is against Objects.

Comment: Go is arguably more object oriented than other languages claiming to be. The definition of _object_ is not tied to the concepts of inheritance or polymorphism. Even though those concepts do exist in one form or another in Go.

Comment: Interfaces can be modeled using UML if the programming language actual does provide enforcement. Go does not, a struct can comply to a usage of that interface but doesn't actual implement interface. The only time when a Struct will get pickedup in code for failure in Go, if you decide to use it in a mixed Struct type scenario (Arrays) and you actually call the method of that Struct, that is suppose to comply with the interface type, as defined in the array structure. Yes it will get caught at usage, but if the interface is never used on that struct, then it will never get picked up for errors.

Comment: by the way, I had similar issues with python on designing for large scale systems, it fails because of the same problem of type enforcement. Although hopefully, Go will catch all those stupid Static type checking errors, which python can not by design. :)

Answer (score -1):

If you like planning and modeling more than programming you should just stick with Java.

If you like building and maintaining the actual code and working systems you should try just planning your Go program on a piece of paper or a whiteboard and get programming.

Comment: I usually do round trips when designing programs, code first, uml for reflection to visualize improvements, then back into code. After numerous round trips, I then model for documentation. The documentation is important if you want to move the code to another language. Also visualizing and talking about what has been written teases out potential problems.